# Why can't I change background color of toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm changing toolbar color like this:

MainActivity.xml

```
    <Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Toolbar>
```

styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#0000ff</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    </style>
```

and MainActivity.java

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setActionBar(toolbar);
```

I can change color colorPrimaryDark and textColorPrimary but can not change colorPrimary, why?

I can change toolbar color like this:

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
```

but cant change using style also why after removing setActionBar(toolbar); the text and title overflow menu gone why?

Comment: post ur java code,of oncreate

Comment: posted oncreate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From XML

```
android:background:"your color"
```

From code

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);  
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(Color.parse("your color"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may remove NoActionBar from parent theme name

Comment: what theme should i use then because if I'm adding actionbar theme its appearing as another actionbar at the top of my own actionbar

Answer (score 0):

put these line

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));
```

Comment: I am also able to change by toolbar.setbackgroundcolor what is the difference between your approach and what i did, also why we have to do getSupportActionbar or getActionbar and if i remove this line the three dots of actionbar(overflow menu) gone

Answer (score 0):

Use this theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` instead